# Discussion Board in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have created a discussion board using jQuery and PHP. Its dynamic. But to get updates I don't know what to do. How would I update the page when new posts and/or new replies come?

Comment: Use `setInterval` function which automatic calls a functions and in that function call a php page using `jquery ajax` and if any updates then reload your `discussion-board div`

Comment: Is there any other way other than sending request to server for each interval of time and load whole date each time. I need a way in which I can retrieve only newly updated data, not to replace whole data..

Comment: You can use `append function` for this, also at server side check if any updates then retrieve only.

Comment: Actually, my situation is this. How to compare that there are new replies of a post and new comments for replies of a post. I'm stuck there..

Answer (score 0):

You can request [ajax request] server after every few seconds and update that result to your discussion board. For that you can user `setTimeInterval` JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code according to your page

```
<div id="results"></div>

<script>
callAjax=function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: 'data.php',
      success: function(data){$('#results').html(data);}
   });
}
setInterval(function(){callAjax()},3000);//update data in every 3 seconds

</script>
```